# Angular fails to load module that it definitely can load

Tags: angularjs

I have been through all the suggested possible duplicates and none fit my situation.

Angular complains that a dependency is not there when it definitely is, as evidenced by angular finding it when I type angular.module in the console (as shown in the attached image).

Can anyone explain how this is possible, and if so how to fix it? I am out of ideas.

[image: firebug console with the error thrown by angular and then angular finding the module it says does not exist]

```
==== app.js ====
angular
  .module('tfApp', [
    'tfConfig',
    'tfResources',
    'tfModals',
    'dashboardApp',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ordinal',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap'
  ])
    .config( ...

==== main.js ====

angular.module('tfApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($filter, apiDate, tournamentService, anglerService) {

==== resource-module.js ====

angular
  .module('tfResources', [
    'tfConfig',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap.modal',
    'ngResource'
  ])
  .config(function ($resourceProvider) {
    $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
  });

==== modal-module.js ====

angular
  .module('tfModals', [
    'tfConfig',
    'tfResources',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap.modal'
  ]);

==== config.js ====

angular.module('tfConfig', [])
  .constant('resourceUrls', { ... 

==== angler-service.js ====

angular.module('tfResources')
  .factory('anglerService', function ($resource, resourceUrls, paramDefaults, customActions) {
```

Comment: It's not complaining about the module, but about the service... Check spelling "anglerService" Should it be "angularService"?

Comment: Can we see how you declared your `MainCtrl` and how you defined your `angular.module('app' [ this is what we want to see ] );` ?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks, but it complains about the module first, anglerService is missing because it's in the module.  I have just double-checked the spelling though just in case, no typo :-(

Comment: @Razvan your wish is my command.  It's worth adding that tfConfig, dashboardApp and tfModals all were working fine before I decided to split off resources into a separate app, and I made them the exact same way.

Comment: are you using minification? if yes, disable it while you troubleshoot.

Comment: What module is anglerService in then? I would check the spelling there.

Comment: it's in tfResources. Spelling is fine

Comment: Can you show what is in your config for the view definition?

Comment: "view definition"? assuming that would be app.js, it's just routeProvider.when( ... ).when(...) etc

Comment: Can you add your `tfResources` module?

Comment: can you show your module declarations for 'tfConfig', 'tfResources' and    'tfModals'?

Comment: So where is your `anglerService` defined?

Comment: @vidalsasoon and @ Razvan: have added both to the OP

Comment: Are you including it on the page? `<script src="resource-module.js"></script>`

Comment: hard to say. I would comment out your existing anglerService factory and declare a new that does nothing and doesn't inject anything into it.

Comment: Found the problem, posted an answer. Thanks for the help everyone. My bad :-$ edit: @vidalsasoon that's pretty much what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem by digging down into this `anglerService` error: As you can see from the code above it comes after `tournamentService`, so that means angular found the `tournamentService` without issue...

It turns out that, as I had just made the module files with a flat structure in one directory, and they were literally called `angler.js`, `module.js` and `tournament.js`, my asset pipeline was loading them in alphabetical order, so `anglerService` was attempting to be defined to a non-existent module whereas `tournamentService` was not.

Restructuring the files to ensure that the module.js is loaded first fixed the problem.

Comment: Yea, this is a usual issue when using **/* patterns when aggregating your ng app :)